# Delphi Parallel programming - multi threading slow

Tags: multithreading, delphi, parallel-processing, delphi-xe2

Good day,

A webcam class has about 30 frames per second, and all of these frames will be saved in a vector(like a queue). Then 3 asynchronous threads will read the queue, and will try to do their jobs(to save these images). Why the queue is overflowing? So the problem is that these threads are slower than the webcam.

```
Procedure TSaveThread.Execute;
begin
   while not terminated  do
   begin
      elElement:=NIL;

      EnterCriticalSection(CritSect);
         if iElementsLength>=0 then
         begin
            elElement:=vElements[iElementsLength];
            Dec(iElementsLength);
         end;
      LeaveCriticalSection(CritSect);

      if elElement<>NIL then
      begin
         JpegImg.Assign(elElement.bmWebcam) ;
         JpegImg.SaveToFile('Save\'+elElement.sTime+'.jpg') ;
         elElement.Free;
      end;

      Sleep(20);
   end;
end;
```

Images added to the queue.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TWebcam.OnSave(Sender:TObject; bmWebcam:TBitmap);
begin
   EnterCriticalSection(CritSect);
      inc(iElementsLength);
      vElements[iElementsLength]:=TElement.Create(bmWebcam);
   LeaveCriticalSection(CritSect);
end;
```

Creating the threads.

```
for i:=0 to 2 do
    TSaveThread.Create(false);
```

The thing is that, these threads are not able to save all these images. Why? How can I improve my threads?

Delphi Version: Delphi XE2

Webcam frame size: 1280x760 or 960x600
Entire source code here: http://pastebin.com/8SekN4TE

Comment: General suggestion - get OmniThreadsLibrary - it outright contains parallel queue primitive exactly to make parallel pipelines

Comment: 2nd suggestion: what is elElement.bmWebcam and JpegImg ? if those are TBitmap - wrappers around windows GDI - ypu'd better avoid them in speed-crytical paths. Use Graphics32 or Vampyre Imaging or some another self-contained library, that does not jumps into Windows GDI layers on every occasion

Comment: suggestion 3: edit your question and put a TAG with your delphi version - that may be crytical to determine which options you have. For example with D2009 i had an awfull experience with TBitmap, TImageList and multithreading

Comment: elElement.bmWebcam is an instance of Graphics.TBitmap class.  JpegImg is an instance of Jpeg.TJpegImage;

Comment: question 4: why use custom array in stead of ready-made TStack class ? And why you use Stack instead of the Queue ?  Or do you actually COPY elements of array when inserting ??????

Comment: See above: get Windows-independent imaging library (like two aforementioned), get OTL and its ready-made parallel queue and pipeline. Then design your code around them. You'd probably need one thread acquring frames and storing them into the queue, and let OTL decide how manmy threads would read it.  Also - does your webcam realyl returning BMP's ? Many webcams to save USB traffic pre-code pictures in JPG in their chip. Maybe you do double work JPG->BMP->JPG ? Dunno...

Comment: Does Delphi have TStack or TDeque?

Comment: How big are the images? How long does it take to perform each JPEG assign and save. Also, move `TElement.Create` outside the critical section.

Comment: You can't use `Sleep` this way and expect decent performance. You need real synchronization.

Comment: That webcam class was not created by me.

Comment: i repeat: **suggestion 3: edit your question and put a TAG with your delphi version** - that may be crytical to determine which options you have. For example with D2009 i had an awfull experience with TBitmap, TImageList and multithreading. It is all version-dependent. But you can google it or you can type in editor TQueue and press F1 to see of it has it. I'd say different Delphi versions have different number of queues. But better drop it all and use readymade library.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - OTL's parallel pipeline already has ready-made synchronization, just take it for granted and use it ;-)

Comment: XE2 has class-based TQueue in contnrs unit and generics TQueue<T> in Generics.Containers unit. You can bake `type MyElement = record ..... end;` and then do `var ImageQueue: TQueue< MyElement>`. Though i think that would result in data copying and suboptimal performance, but together with JPG conversion it probably would not mean much

Comment: depending on your disk and cache it takes an amount of time to create the file and write the content and close it. More threads (parallel read/write) will increase this time using the same physical drive. You should also use sleep(20) only if you did not find an element.

Comment: http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/11/multistage-processes-with.html

Comment: @SirRufo great point! he need camera-limited (1 thread) image acquisition, -> input queue -> CPU-limited (multi-thread, load-balanced) conversion threads, -> output queue -> HDD-limited files writer (one per physical HDD - probably single thread again).
That is pipeline!

Comment: I found that if I will create the number of threads to 20 for instance, the CPU will be overclocking, and still has the same problem.

Comment: I didn't get it. Here is the entire source code http://pastebin.com/vqqavqNb Is it hard to use OTL?

Comment: @DavidHefferman why bother ? he would still have CryticalSection inside FastMM

Comment: @user you would need to learn. Was it hard to learn OOP ? i started with assembler and classic Basic(not Visual Basic), then i switched to Turbo Pascal and learned structural programming. It was hard - but then it allowed me to do things almost impossible with Basic spaghetti. Then OOP came and i HATED it, ugly bloated TurboPascal 6.0 ! But it allow to make programs that would take AGES in structural types. With OTL you'd have to learn new concepts and restrictions. But you can start with demo's and modify them to your needs. Then OTL'd solve you dozens of problems you not yet realized u have!

Comment: And do not use Windows-based TBitmap for speed-crytical; things. Graphics32.org or Vampyre or some other completely independent objects to store pictures.

Comment: *the CPU will be overclocking, and still has the same problem* - because Sleep(20) is NOT synchronization. You may do it explicitlye - if the queue is empty - then thread should suspend itself. When you add new element to queue you should scan the threads pool and wake some thread if it is sleeping. Well, not on the 1st image - perhaps on the second or third ones.. Well but if there was zero awake threads - then do awake on 1st image...   - and that is ONLY tpool planning. Doo you understand why it needed ? can you make proper way what u don't understand ? OTL needs & worth learning, trust me.

Comment: About pasted code:
"Constructor TElement.Create(bmWebcam: TBitmap);" - i'd rather used records than objects. No need to trash Heap (it badly scales on multithreading).
" self.bmWebcam:=TBitmap.Create;" - weird! you should just    
  `self.bmWebcam.Width := bmWebcam`' - don't copy data and create redundant objects - pass the pointer and let some worker thread free it later. TfrMain.OnSave should not free it! *i still hope you'd make it via OTL pipeline, but those suggestions would be true there too*

Comment: @Arioch'The You assume that the only purpose of `TElement.Create(bmWebcam)` is to make a single call to `GetMem`.

Comment: The data from the initial bmWebcam returned from the Webcam is not destroyed. So all of these instances of TElement must have their own frame.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan open pastebin link - what is more positive purpose there ?

Comment: @Arioch'The As I suspected. `TElement.Create` does a whole load more than a single `GetMem`

Comment: @user - come on! you DO destroy it as last line of your OnSave!
And you could do bmp.Assign(bmWebCam) instead :-) It is pity that your WebCom class only can give you TBitmap - which is rooted in Win32 internals and its behavior is controlled by Microsoft, not by you...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and that lot is either redundant (creating and copying new TBitmap) or would not change if substituted by record.

Comment: @Arioch'The Probably `TWebcam.OnSave` has to take a copy

Comment: the bmWebcam from the TWebcam.OnSave will never be destroyed(it is the same all this time)

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake of mine. This is the working code http://pastebin.com/8SekN4TE

Comment: @user personally i'd then i'd made b := TBitmap32.Create, and passed b as the element, and element would be record to me. I'd strive to get rid of TBitmap ASAP, but well, there is that JPEG conversion problem...
 ******* 
But well, David is right - find different JPEG conversion libraries on Torry.net or Delphi SuperPages or other collectors. Vamypre Imaging, GraphicEx, GDI+ - just to name a few ou of the mind - find the most fast one. When you test and choose one - see if it requires TBitmap or can have more basic input.  Then i difinitely sggest you to start with pipeline demo and rework it

Comment: Well, if possible i'd even made just array of bytes to store temporary bitmap, rather than object, if only some library would be possible to consume it.  And by the way does your camera have DirectX DirectShow-compatible drivers ?

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of this kind of video processing, you might want to look into the Mitov library: www.mitov.com. We've been VERY happy with it for the past 3 years. It's highly optimized, multi-threaded, easy-to-use and FAST. If you are unable to resolve your speed issues, you could use Mitov or other tools to save the live video data to disk and then read the .avi file back at your own speed.  And, even with live data, you can turn on threading in the components and enable blocking and it will handle a queue of the depth you specify. The author provides great support.

Comment: Robert Frank Thank you, I have done with this multi-threading solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MultiThreadding will not speed up your Media (HardDrive).

In fact it can **slow down** with parallel write access.

At first you have to measure if your Media (HardDisk) is able to store an image in less than 33ms - because every 33.333ms you will get a new image from webcam.

If not, you can't expect to get this running.

You should have to (and/or)

- use more hard disks (e.g. one per thread)
- use more cache (e.g. Cache Controller)
- use faster hard disks (e.g. SSD)
- use smaller images (decrease resolution)
- drop some images

And don't loose time if you need to be fast

```
if elElement<>NIL then
  begin
     JpegImg.Assign(elElement.bmWebcam) ;
     JpegImg.SaveToFile('Save\' + elElement.sTime + '.jpg' );
     elElement.Free;
  end
else
  Sleep(20);
```

OTL will not help to get your media faster, but would be much cleaner :o)

So you should have a look at

Comment: modern HHD have approx 100MB per second minimum linear speed. Given it is de-fragmented, exclusively used to save pictures and assuming file caching work okay, the access would be near linear, let's be safe anf estimate 75MB/sec

75 MB/sec / 30 fps would be 2,5 MB per picture. I think that is fare enough

Comment: How many threads should I start? A jpg image is less than 100kb

Comment: Disk access is not the bottleneck here.

Comment: @Arioch'The this theoretical performance can be reached using a filestream and storing all images into. It is a great difference to save 1024 files with 1KB or 1 file with 1MB

Comment: @user: i told you - one thread for reading camera, one thread per HDD to save files, and from one to CPU cores count of converter threads, depending how fast they would be - it should dynamically change while program is running depending on input queue load.

Comment: @SirRufo - turn write cache on for HDD Policy  and it would update MFT rare enough so that would not count. Access would be ALMOST linear.

Comment: @SirRufo "So you should have a look at" - smth missed ?

Comment: @Arioch'The referenced to OTL :o)

Comment: That thing with Sleep(20) it is really good. So if I would use a stream and I will save the 90kb images in that stream will this increase my performance?

Comment: @user What makes you think that disk IO is an issue?

Comment: My machine (VM) will consume 100ms per image (219kb size)

Comment: and the main consumer is not Disk IO but conversion Bitmap to JPEG

Comment: @user - you should not remove Sleep completely - you should at least get leave it as Sleep(0) aka Yield. As a polite way to let other threads run. Proper solution would be starting-stopping threads as required. Well, after you'd get reasonable speed. As of now, try to think about all the advices here (in backgrond) and go search for fast JPEG libraries, preferably those that can take plain byte pointer as input rather than TBitmap object.

Comment: @Sir Rufo - VM, antiviri, there are many ways to slow it down. but well, since his images are 150KB average - that is not the issue copletely.

Comment: @Arioch'The David H pointed out the main problem in his answer

Comment: Sir Rufo, I found your post very useful, and I think it is a good solution! The else sleep(20) it is a solution to my problem.

Comment: @user - that mean it solved it or not ? if it did - accept his answer

Answer (score 15):

I wrote the following program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg, 
  System.IOUtils, System.Diagnostics;

var
  i: Integer;
  bmp: TBitmap;
  jpeg: TJPEGImage;
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;

begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.SetSize(1280, 760);
  jpeg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for i := 1 to 100 do begin
    jpeg.Assign(bmp);
    jpeg.SaveToFile('C:\desktop\temp\'+TPath.GetRandomFileName);
  end;
  Writeln(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  Readln;
end.
```

It converts 1280x760 pixel bitmaps to JPEG images, and then saves to disk. It does so 100 times. On my machine this takes 9 seconds. That's a throughput of 11 images per second. If I skip the convert to JPEG step and save the bitmap directly I can get a through put of 150 images per second. Clearly the conversion to JPEG is a bottleneck.

You are looking for 30 images per second. Whilst multi-threading helps, I suspect you have a quad core machine. One processor for the webcam, and three for the saving. So if you only have three threads available, then you are probably going to struggle to reach the required throughput of 30 frames per second. Theoretical peak on my machine would be 33. If you don't achieve 30 frames per second then your queue will obviously overflow.

The obvious conclusion is that you need to find a faster JPEG conversion library. I'm quite sure that such libraries exist. For example, I think that `libjpeg` should be a lot faster.

As for your existing code there are some obvious flaws:

1. `Sleep` should usually be avoided. In your case it is suicidal to sleep if the last attempt to pull an image succeeded. Don't do that. You should use a real threaded queue. One that allow proper blocking waits on synchronization objects. It's actually pretty trivial to make one yourself using event objects and your favourite non-threaded queue.
2. You are holding the lock whilst calling `TElement.Create(bmWebcam)`. That is going to hinder scaling. Assign `TElement.Create(bmWebcam)` to a local variable, outside the lock. And then assign to the shared data inside the lock.

So, you could check these ideas out by first of all removing the call to `Sleep`. And then changing `TWebcam.OnSave` to look like this:

```
Procedure TWebcam.OnSave(Sender:TObject; bmWebcam:TBitmap);
var
  NewElement: TElement;
begin
  NewElement := TElement.Create(bmWebcam);
  EnterCriticalSection(CritSect);
    inc(iElementsLength);
    vElements[iElementsLength] := NewElement;
  LeaveCriticalSection(CritSect);
end;
```

These suggestions will help a little, but I think you'll need to tackle the fundamental problem, namely the JPEG conversion.

Comment: You should be able to do the maths yourself. Theoretical peak throughput for 3 threads on my machine would be 33 frames per second. That perilously close to the minimum throughput you need to achieve. Your poor threading code (Sleep, locks that are held too long) means you can't achieve theoretical peak. Plus there will be a lack of scaling on disk IO, although that's not the main bottleneck.

Comment: If I will open many Threads like 20, why this doesn't help me.

Comment: @David - you'd better separate saving and converting tasks :-)  PS: blins gueess: three cores - as many threads as he wanted to create :-)

Comment: My machine has only 2 processors

Comment: @David - you source BMP is all-black - it is not natural target of JPG libraries! can you take some real-life picture for the source BMP ? faces or trees or something that JPEG algo was created for.

Comment: I agree that a single IO thread would be a better design. But it won't help that much since converting is, by my estimate, around 10 times as big a task as saving.

Comment: @user 2 real cores or HyperThreading ? ;-) Well, if you have 2 cores, then creating 3 identical tasks would only brake them, like the croud fails to run into narrow door. But creating of proper quantity of worker threads is done automatically in OTL :-P

Comment: @Arioch'The It makes little difference to use a more realistic image. Changes timings by 10%. That's probably on the disk IO because the files that go out are much bigger.

Comment: @user Adding more threads won't help unless you have processors on which to run the threads. A dual core machine does not have enough oomph to do this task.

Comment: @Arioch'The How would OTL help here? Two processors are not enough.

Comment: @user depends how many FPU's you have. Intel HyperThreading and latest AMD CPUs report two times mroe cores than they really have. That works okay on integral calculations like Office work etc. But that would trash floating-point performance :-) But for most popular CPUs yes - max number of floating points working threads - is a number of cores, not more.

Comment: @David For general applciation design. Tomorrow requirements would change, in a week he'd have to deploy to 6-core computer - how can we know ? better do leart good design on simplistic example this project shows. I actually think that best application would be Microsoft GraphEdit :-D But that is not the reason not to try do it yourself.

Comment: @Arioch'The Actually today's hyperthreading (as opposed to awful P4 version) scales quite well with FPU calculations. But even with 4 logical processors, the throughput will not be there. Agreed that threading should be done right. It just won't help here on his current machine. JPEG conversion is the bottleneck. That's what needs to be addressed.

Comment: i meant Atom. i don;'t remember if i5 3xxx CPUs exist with dual-core and HT, i thought HT starts at 4-cores i5 to i7 boundary. Maybe i need to check the facts though